# ParseInt crashes on longer numbers

Tags: java, android, json, parseint

After a few weeks i finally found out how to parse my numbers through my app. But now the app crashes when given a number in the following format: `92839283982938` or `22.483.84.3883`.

I just dont know how to make it accept those number formats. The problem is connected to a barcode scanner, so i really need it to accept those number formats.

The code i used to parse is:

```
JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(xyz)-1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For longer number you should use `Long.parseLong()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`.

Next case `22.483.84.3883` not a numeric. You will get `NumberFormatException` from here.

You can use

```
try{
   long val=Long.parseLong("xxxx")
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   // exception 
}
```

If you want to consider `22.483.84.3883` or `22-483-84-3883` as a valid case, you need to replace `.` or `-` first.

Eg:

```
 long val=Long.parseLong("22.483.84.3883".replaceAll("\\.", ""));
 System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: do you know how i can make it accept 22.483.84.3883? or one that contains dashes?

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, what do i need to replace to make it valid?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long.parseLong` instead. Integer type can't contain such large numbers (the max value of Integer is 2^31-1, which is much smaller than 92839283982938). In addition, you should eliminate the dots.

Try :

```
JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(Long.parseLong(xyz.replace(".",""))-1);
```

Comment: will it also accept numbers with multiple breakpoints like .? or dashes?

Comment: @derhak You should remove the breakpoints before parsing the number.